# NMDS Error in cov.wt: weights must be non-negative and not all zero

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to make an NMDS plot for how OTUs vary with soil type.

Here is a section of my code after reading in my OTU table and metadata file:

```
# Calculate distance for NMDS
sol=metaMDS(DATA1)

# NMDS data frame
NMDS = data.frame(MDS1 = sol$points[,1], MDS2 = sol$points[,2],group=meta$Soil.type)
NMDS.mean=aggregate(NMDS[,1:2],list(group=meta$Soil.type),mean)

# Vegan Cov Ellipse function
veganCovEllipse<-function (cov, center = c(0, 0), scale = 1, npoints = 100) 
{
  theta <- (0:npoints) * 2 * pi/npoints
  Circle <- cbind(cos(theta), sin(theta))
  t(center + scale * t(Circle %*% chol(cov)))
}

df_ell <- data.frame()
for(g in levels(NMDS$group)){
  df_ell <- rbind(df_ell, cbind(as.data.frame(with(NMDS[NMDS$group==g,],
                                               veganCovEllipse(cov.wt(cbind(MDS1,MDS2),wt=rep(1/length(MDS1),length(MDS1)))$cov,center=c(mean(MDS1),mean(MDS2)))))
                            ,group=g))
}
```

At this point, I get the following error:

```
Error in cov.wt(cbind(MDS1, MDS2), wt = rep(1/length(MDS1), length(MDS1))) : 
  weights must be non-negative and not all zero
```

Here is a subset of my NMDS data frame:

```
         MDS1        MDS2                    group
B1_02   -0.01562695 -0.39211505    Sandy clay in valleys
B1_0210 -0.83751037 -0.17452227    Sandy clay in valleys
B1_1020 -0.49050044 -0.19169209    Sandy clay in valleys
B1_Litt  0.69079105 -0.07051786    Sandy clay in valleys
B2_0210 -0.75019323  0.30193393    Sandy clay in valleys
B2_1020 -1.21495108  0.01854564    Sandy clay in valleys
B2_Litt  0.75491704 -0.08715606    Sandy clay in valleys
```

I have run this code before using different metadata and OTU files, so I think the code should be fine. The problem must be with the files I'm using this time. I don't understand the error, but I'm guessing that it is referring to the negative MDS1 and MDS2 values in my NMDS data frame.

I have found nothing online about how to deal with issue and I'm at a loss.

Is there a way that I can get this code to work even with negative values?

Comment: So what is `length(MDS1)`? Looks like `MDS1`  is a variable within a data frame that is not visible to `cov.wt()`.

Comment: Length(MDS1) refers to the length of the vector list, MDS1. I made MDS1 when I was creating the NMDS data frame. I've used this exact code successfully before using different input files, so MDS1 should be visible

Comment: Do you *hope* that `length(MDS1)` refers to the length of `MDS1` or do you *know* it refers to the length of `MDS1`? That is, did you try? In the code in your post, `MDS1` is not visible. The error message comes form `cov.wt()` which receives weights `rep(1/length(MDS1), length(MDS1))`. These weights are in no way related to negative values of `MDS1`, but only to the length of `MDS1`.

Comment: By any chance, is any of your `groups` empty? The error comes from `cov.wt`, and with `wt = (1/0, 0)` (i.e., zero-length `groups`) you get exactly the error message that you reported in your post.